# SolR : NullPointerException when using spellcheck.q

Tags: solr, nullpointerexception, spell-checking

I've already posted about a problem which brought me to this error, but I write it something more specific about the error:

When I use spellcheck.q in my query to define what will be "spellchecked", I always have this error, for every configuration I try:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent.getTokens(SpellCheckComponent.java:476)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent.process(SpellCheckComponent.java:131)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:202)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1368)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

All my other functions works great, this is the only thing which doesn't work at all, just when I add "&spellcheck.q=my%20sentence" in the query...

Has anyone already have solved this problem?

Comment: what version of Solr are you using?

Comment: I've run some tests, and I found that it makes this error when i add a spellcheck component to a handler and i try to use spellcheck.q

So spellcheck.q works with this kind of use :

http://localhost:8983/solr/db/suggest_full?q=american%20israel&spellcheck.q=american%20israel&qt=spellchecker (with the original spellchecker of db)

But this spellchecker has the class solr.SpellCheckerRequestHandler that doesn't have all the options I want (like collation).

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed in trunk.

So get latest code from SVN or a nightly build.

Comment: I've tried with the version solr-4.0-2011-08-22_08-06-47 and it did the same error. Moreover my bug report on jira is still open, so I don't think it's fixed :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2726?focusedCommentId=13090274#comment-13090274

Comment: It is fixed now :) (or so the JIRA issue says)